# How do I dismiss custom dropdown in Angular?

Tags: angular

I created a custom control that will create a `<ul>` element based on the search results form the criteria entered into a text box. When the user clicks or taps on one of the items in the drop down it selects the item. However, if the user changes their mind I would like to be able to hide the `<ul>` element. What do I need to do in order to capture clicks anywhere else (that's not an `<li>` in the now visible ) element to hide the `<ul>`?

On a side note if I have a `FormControl` and I call `setValue()`, it appears I need to mark it dirty by hand in order for the parent `FormGroup` to become dirty. Is that normal or is there something I need to do when calling `setValue()` to ensure the value change gets propagated up the form tree?

### Update

I'm adding in my template and component code. The `(blur)` method doesn't seem to be working. Possibly because I'm testing on an iPad simulator. I haven't tried it with different browsers. I'm posting the important excerpts from my template and component code to see if there's something obvious that I can do differently to get the desired behavior.

**template**

```
...
<div class="defect-detail" [formGroup]="defectForm">
...
  <my-date-picker formControlName="completedDate" [options]="datePickerOptions"></my-date-picker>
...
  <div class="assigned-trade">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
    <input type="text" [formControl]='search' (blur)="showTradesSearchResults = false">
      <ul *ngIf="list$ | async as data" [ngStyle]="{'display' : showTradesSearchResults ? '' : 'none'}">
        <li *ngFor="let trade of data" data-id="{{trade.value}}" (click)="selectTrade(trade)">
          {{trade.text}}
        </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
...
  <div class="repair-status" (click)="showRepairStates = !showRepairStates" (blur)="showRepairStates = false">
    {{repairStatus}}
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </div>
  <ul *ngIf="showRepairStates">
    <li *ngFor="let opt of repairStates" (click)="selectRepairState($event)" data-id="{{opt.value}}">{{opt.text}}.    </li>
  </ul>
...
  <button [ngClass]="{'hbp-btn-blue' : !defect.complete}" class="form-control" (click)="complete()" *ngIf="defect.repairStatus == 6">
    Complete
  </button>
...
</div>
...
```

**component**

```
...
selectRepairState(event) {
  console.log("Selecting Repair State");
  //this.defect.repairStatus = +event.target.id;

  this.defect.complete = false;
  let repairStatus = this.defectForm.get('repairStatus');
  repairStatus.setValue(+event.target.id);
  repairStatus.markAsDirty();
  this.showRepairStates = false;
}

selectTrade(trade) {
  console.log("select trade");
  console.debug(trade);

  let assignedTrade = this.defectForm.get('assignedTrade');
  assignedTrade.setValue(trade);
  assignedTrade.markAsDirty();

  this.search.patchValue(trade.text, { emitEvent: false });
  this.showTradesSearchResults = false;
}
...
complete(): void {
  console.log('Completing ');
  this.defect.complete = true;
  let newDateValue = DatePickerUtil.fromDate(new Date());
  let completedDate = this.defectForm.get('completedDate');
  completedDate.patchValue(newDateValue);
  completedDate.markAsDirty();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your first question is that you simply need to listen to `blur` event:

```
<ul *ngIf="showUL"></ul>
...
<div id="parent" (blur)="hideUL()"></div>
```

And

```
hideUL() {
   this.showUL = false;
}
```

As simple as that.

The answer to your second question on the other hand is no, you shouldn't need to set dirty manually and that means you're doing something wrong.

But if you want to do it you should use the `markAsDirty` method, like this:

```
FormControl.markAsDirty();
```

Comment: Ok. Glad to know the first question has a simple solution. As for the second question I'm already using the `markAsDirty()` method. But it doesn't seem like I should have to. Guess I'll keep poking around and see what I can find. Incidentally if I change a control through the UI then the parent FG gets updated. If I call setValue() I have to set the FC to dirty manually. Do I need to use an `<input>` with `formControlName' set the the name of the corresponding control in order to get the dirty flag to propagate?

Comment: Yes if you use the DOM element and its events it will be done as normal, if you put your code up maybe I will have a look and help out @Colin

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HostListener` decorator to listen for click events outside:

```
  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  clickedOutside($event) {
    // here you can hide your dropdown
  }
```

Regarding second question I guess dirty flag is only set when user interacts with control. Or you set it manually.